# ReactNative Stack Navigation is not a function

Tags: react-native

I tryed to add the Drawer.Navigator to Stack.Navigator how describe in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators but faced issue **navigation.openDriver is not a function** when trying open menu by button

`onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}`

[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where did you use 'MenuButton' component?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use **useNavigation()** instead, like following:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
return (
    <Button onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
       <Icon active name="menu"/>
    </Button>
)
```